# Return an Boolean array by matching words in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

The function `keywordusage` should return which of the keywords are present in the text in the form of **boolean array** like:  `array: [true, false, false]`. based on the second argument to the function. Right now, I am able to return only the `true` values, I do not know how to return `false` values when the case is false. The code is below. The output should be **[true, false, false]**

```
    {function keywordusage(str,strArr){
var count = [];
var found = true;
var notfound = false;
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var wordsLength = words.length;
  var ArrLength = strArr.length;
   for(var i = 0; i < ArrLength; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < wordsLength; j++){
        if(words[j]===strArr[i])
        count.push(true);
      }
  }
  return count;
 }

document.write(keywordusage('Dive Into Python is a free book for experienced programmers', ['Python', 'python', 'scala']));}
```

Comment: `else{count.push(false);}`?

Comment: yea thats true but that will include all the false from the second string, as i am running two loops. like there will be false value for Dive , Into etc which i dont want. i just want true or false if the words in the second array match or does not match. the result should be array with only 3 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function keywordusage(text, keywords) {
    var elements = text.split(" ");
    var result = Array();
    for (var i=0; i < keywords.length;i++){
        if (elements.indexOf(keywords[i]) >= 0)
            result[i] = true;
        else
            result[i] = false;
    }//end of for loop
    return result;
}

var result = keywordusage('Dive Into Python is a free book for experienced programmers', ['Python', 'python', 'scala']);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a map to check if words in your pattern array are in the string :

```js
var keywordusage = (str, strArr) => strArr.map(x => str.split(" ").indexOf(x) !== -1);
console.log(keywordusage('Dive Into Python is a free book for experienced programmers', ['Python', 'python', 'scala']));
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use the   array.map()  function  which essentially is a command that allows you to create a new array by executing a function on every value in an existing array.

In this case   array1  already exists,   and returnArray is undefined

Then we call `returnArray` equals  "map every value from array1 by checking to see `textString.indexOf(array1)`  is greater than -1

`.indexOf()` returns   the position of a string within a string, or -1  if that string doesn't exist.

```js
function keywordusage(array1, textString) {
  var returnArray = array1.map(x => textString.indexOf(x) > -1);
  return returnArray;
}

// demonstration of usage
var checkArray = ["the", "quick", "brown"];
var checkString = "the quick red fox jumped over the lazy dog";

console.log(JSON.stringify(keywordusage(checkArray, checkString)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [javascript map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Checkout below code

```js
function keywordusage(str, strArr) {
  var count = [];
  strArr.map(function(s) {
    return count.push(str.indexOf(s) !== -1);
  });
  console.log(count);
  return count;
}

document.write(keywordusage('Dive Into Python is a free book for experienced programmers', ['Python', 'python', 'scala']));
```

Hope this will help you (y).